# CSS style if/else statement not responding

Tags: php, css

I am trying to have set the position of my li element according to the value of the variable that I will be displaying. For some reason this doesn't seem to be working.  Does anyone see anything wrong with my code? Thanks

```
echo "<li class=\"compensation_post posts_values\" if($compensation == \"Free\") {style=\"left: 540px;\"}>$compensation</li>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP can parse variables in a double-quoted string, but not conditions. So you're going to need to break this out in one of two ways:

Separated:

```
$style = '';
if ($compensation == "Free")
  $style = " style=\"left:540px;\"";
echo "<li class=\"compensation_post posts_values\"$style>$compensation</li>";
```

Or in-line:

```
echo "<li class=\"compensation_post posts_values\" "
   . ($compensation == "Free" ? "style=\"left:540px;" : "")
   . ">$compensation</li>";
```

I suppose you can also go in and out of php code like:

```
?><li class=\"compensation_post posts_values\" <?= ($compensation == "Free" ? "style=\"left:540px;\"" : ""); ?>>$compensation</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an if statement like that. Instead, you could use a shorthand if. Something like this should work:

`echo "<li class=\"compensation_post posts_values\"" . (($compensation == 'Free') ? 'style=\"left: 540px;\" : '') . ">$compensation</li>";`

Or, you could do like this:

`if ($compensation == 'Free')

$style = 'style="left: 540px;"';

echo "<li class=\"compensation_post posts_values\" $style>$compensation</li>";`